# WaitAll vs WhenAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

What is the difference between `Task.WaitAll()` and `Task.WhenAll()` from the Async CTP?
Can you provide some sample code to illustrate the different use cases?

Answer (score 744, accepted):

`Task.WaitAll` blocks the current thread until everything has completed.

`Task.WhenAll` returns a *task* which represents the action of waiting until everything has completed.

That means that from an async method, you can use:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

... which means your method will continue when everything's completed, but you won't tie up a thread to just hang around until that time.

Comment: Does this assume all the tasks you're waiting on are actually doing work on another thread?

Comment: @VincePanuccio As far as i know, a new thread will be used for each task if *needed*, the framework will get the context of the code and if its long-running operation then probably a new thread will be used.

Comment: After much reading, It is clear that async has nothing to do with threads http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: @Vince: I think "nothing to do with threads" is an overstatement, and it's important to understand how async operations interact with threads.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think statement `await TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks)` also block the current thread as well.

Comment: @KevinBui: No, it shouldn't *block* it - it will *await* the task returned by `WhenAll`, but that's not the same as blocking the thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet Perhaps the precise distinction between those two is too subtle for me. Can you point me (and possibly, the rest of us) at some reference that will make clear the difference?

Comment: @CatShoes: Not really - I've explained it as well as I can already. I guess I could give an analogy - it's like the difference between ordering a takeaway and then standing by the door waiting for it to arrive, vs ordering a takeaway, doing other stuff and then opening the door when the courier arrives...

Comment: OK.  The await keyword (when used properly all the way down) uses a software interrupt to reenter code at the spot where it is placed when the software interrupt triggers.  Then it immediately exits because the software interrupt will bring it back.  So, there is no thread, even the current one has exited.

Comment: @PRMan: Well the await keyword causes `OnCompleted` to be called provide the callback (assuming the awaitable hasn't already completed). Exactly how that's implemented is precisely that - an implementation detail.

Answer (score 134):

While JonSkeet's answer explains the difference in a typically excellent way there is another difference: *exception handling*.

`Task.WaitAll` throws an `AggregateException` when any of the tasks throws and you can examine all thrown exceptions. The `await` in `await Task.WhenAll` unwraps the `AggregateException` and 'returns' only the first exception.

When the program below executes with `await Task.WhenAll(taskArray)` the output is as follows.

```
19/11/2016 12:18:37 AM: Task 1 started
19/11/2016 12:18:37 AM: Task 3 started
19/11/2016 12:18:37 AM: Task 2 started
Caught Exception in Main at 19/11/2016 12:18:40 AM: Task 1 throwing at 19/11/2016 12:18:38 AM
Done.
```

When the program below is executed with `Task.WaitAll(taskArray)` the output is as follows.

```
19/11/2016 12:19:29 AM: Task 1 started
19/11/2016 12:19:29 AM: Task 2 started
19/11/2016 12:19:29 AM: Task 3 started
Caught AggregateException in Main at 19/11/2016 12:19:32 AM: Task 1 throwing at 19/11/2016 12:19:30 AM
Caught AggregateException in Main at 19/11/2016 12:19:32 AM: Task 2 throwing at 19/11/2016 12:19:31 AM
Caught AggregateException in Main at 19/11/2016 12:19:32 AM: Task 3 throwing at 19/11/2016 12:19:32 AM
Done.
```

The program:

```
class MyAmazingProgram
{
    public class CustomException : Exception
    {
        public CustomException(String message) : base(message)
        { }
    }

    static void WaitAndThrow(int id, int waitInMs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow}: Task {id} started");

        Thread.Sleep(waitInMs);
        throw new CustomException($"Task {id} throwing at {DateTime.UtcNow}");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await MyAmazingMethodAsync();
        }).Wait();

    }

    static async Task MyAmazingMethodAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            Task[] taskArray = { Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WaitAndThrow(1, 1000)),
                                 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WaitAndThrow(2, 2000)),
                                 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WaitAndThrow(3, 3000)) };

            Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
            //await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
            Console.WriteLine("This isn't going to happen");
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var inner in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Caught AggregateException in Main at {DateTime.UtcNow}: " + inner.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Caught Exception in Main at {DateTime.UtcNow}: " + ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This explanation was useful in the scenario I'm currently working. Perhaps not the "biggest practical difference", but definitely a good call out.

Comment: The exception handling being biggest practical difference might be more applicable to the comparison between `await t1; await t2; await t3;` vs `await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3);`

Comment: Doesn't this exception behaviour contradict the docs here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___) 
"If any of the supplied tasks completes in a faulted state, the returned task will also complete in a Faulted state, where its exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of unwrapped exceptions from each of the supplied tasks."

Comment: I consider this to be an artifact of `await`, not a difference between the two methods. Both propagate an `AggregateException`, either throwing directly or through a property (the [`Task.Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception) property).

Answer (score 42):

As an example of the difference --
 if you have a task that does something with the UI thread (e.g. a task that represents an animation in a Storyboard) if you `Task.WaitAll()` then the UI thread is blocked and the UI is never updated.
  if you use `await Task.WhenAll()` then the UI thread is not blocked, and the UI will be updated.

Comment: That could ve avoided if you set ConfigureAwait(false); on the waited tasks. I won't recommend the use WaitAll, though

Comment: @X.Otano No. Never use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on a UI thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62697471/109941

Answer (score 29):

What do they do:

- Internally both do the same thing.

---

What's the difference:

- **WaitAll** is a blocking call
- **WhenAll** - not - code will continue executing

---

Use which when:

- **WaitAll** when cannot continue without having the result
- **WhenAll** when what just to be notified, not blocked

Comment: @MartinRhodes But what if you don't await it immediately, but continue with some other work and _then_ await it? You don't have that possibility with `WaitAll` as I understand it.

Comment: @Jeppe Wouldn't you just differ the call to `Task.WaitAll` _after_ you did your some other work? I mean, instead of calling it right after starting your tasks.