# Requesting same web service multiple times asynchronously

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, soap

I'm creating a razor view that consumes a web service (not belonging to our organisation). The way the service calls are made are as follows:

1. Call the first method, which returns a number of guids.
2. **For each** of these guids, call the second service asynchronously to return the record.

I have to make the service method calls asynchronously for performance. The problem I'm having is that I currently have no way of waiting until **ALL** the responses are available before returning the records back to the view. I've got this far:

Method to return records to razor view:

```
    public List<ProactisContract> GetContractsList()
    {
        List<Guid> contractIds = GetAmendedContracts();
        GetContractDetails(contractIds);

        //Test
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        return _contractList;
    }
```

This is the second method that loops through the guids from the first call, making a service request for each record:

```
    private void GetContractDetails(List<Guid> contractIds)
    {
        foreach (var recId in contractIds)
        {
            var request = new GetContractDetailsRequest { Authentication = _authorisation, ContractGuid = recId, ContractNumber = "string", SummaryOnly = true };

            AsyncCallback asyncCallback = GetContractDetailsCallBack;

            _service.BeginGetContractDetails(request, asyncCallback, _service);
        }
    }

    private void GetContractDetailsCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        var response = _service.EndGetContractDetails(asyncResult);

        lock (_contractList)
        {
            var contract = new ProactisContract
            {
                /*Assign property values*/
            };
            _contractList.Add(contract);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can **wait** until all the responses are received before returning the List<> back to the razor view?

Thanks

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate question, have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337671/using-async-await-for-multiple-tasks

Comment: I hadn't. Thanks for the suggestion. Although this is not a duplicate IMO as my methods don't return a task, therefore I have nothing to get a handle on.

Comment: Ah I didn't see that, my apologies.

Comment: I've posted an answer below, please let me know if that does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a global counter variable equal to the length of contractIds and then every time a callback finishes, you decrease the counter by 1, then you do a

```
while (counter != 0)
{
}
```

where you're sleeping the threads.

Definitely not an elegant solution by any means but I think it will work.  I'm sure someone else here will provide a better solution but in the meantime, mine should solve your problem.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!