# C# - Parallel.ForEach and Async combination

Tags: c#

I've a problem with parallel.foreach and async combination.
Here is my code -

```
new Thread(() =>{
     //doing some stuff here
     Parallel.ForEach(.....,ParallelOption,async(j,loopState) =>
     {
        //await some stuff here like:
       // HttpResponseMessage res = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
      // UpdateUI
     }
}).Start();
```

Now, my problem is how can I be sure of the loop has completed all jobs? It just ends in few seconds but UIUpdateing will continue for much more time.
How its possible to wait for the  `await httpClient.GetAsync(url)`  to complete and then update the UI?

Comment: are you saying that they are not synchronized?

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava, he's saying that `Parallel.ForEach` completes before all of the tasks started by the loop body have the chance to complete. This is a well-known problem. `Parallel.ForEach` is not designed to work with `async` delegates.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy exactly , do you have any  idea what should i have to do ? anotherway or something esle ? thanks.

Comment: @Mahdi, use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23139769/1644813) if you're ok with all of the tasks running at the same time, or use TPL Dataflow if you need limited degree of parallelism.

Comment: You are using a new thread, `Parallel.ForEach` and TPL (async/await). Each tool has a different purpose and should never be combined. Because the actual work is being done using TPL you should just get rid of the thread and `Parallel.ForEach`. If you create many tasks you can wait for them all to complete using `Task.WhenAll`.

Answer (score 2):

[Using async/await for multiple tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337671/using-async-await-for-multiple-tasks)

```
return Task.WhenAll(ids.Select(i => DoSomething(1, i, blogClient)));
```

I don't know what's in your actual loop code.  If you put more up I can make this more specific.  Basically though you use WhenAll to await all of the ascnc tasksf