# How to apply asynchronous inside Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Inside the `Parallel.ForEach` method when I use an asynchronous method `DownloadWebsiteAsync` to get an external resource the calling method `executeAsync_Click` does not await the `RunDownloadParallelAsync` method and prints the result before `RunDownloadParallelAsync` finishes its work.
When I change `DownloadWebsiteAsync` to `DownloadWebsiteSync` (which works in a synchronous way) everything is working well.

```cs
private async void executeAsync_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var results = await DemoMethods.RunDownloadParallelAsync();
    PrintResults(results);

    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    resultsWindow.Text += $"Total execution time: { elapsedMs }";
}

public static async Task<List<WebsiteDataModel>> RunDownloadParallelAsync()
{
    List<string> websites = PrepData();
    List<WebsiteDataModel> output = new List<WebsiteDataModel>();
    
    await Task.Run(() =>
        Parallel.ForEach<string>(websites, async (site) =>
        {
            WebsiteDataModel results =await DownloadWebsiteAsync(site);
            output.Add(results);
        })
    );
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a need for parallelism here. You could simply loop through all your websites, call `DownloadWebsiteAsync`, place the resulting `Task<WebsiteDataModel>` in a list (say `downloadTasks`), and after calling `DownloadWebsiteAsync` on all websites (after the loop) call `await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks)` and then get the results like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197786/9363973)

Comment: You do not need `Parallel.ForEach` if your methods are `async`, this adds nothing. What you're doing now is starting a separate thread which starts threads which start tasks, and to make things worse this still doesn't work correctly since `output.Add` isn't thread safe! Consider `Task.WhenAll` instead.

Comment: If you wish to rate limit the number of requests that can run together you can do something like this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/ . If you only have a small number of tasks, you might be better off just using `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: The `Parallel.ForEach` is not async-friendly. @Servy [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda) is the correct duplicate IMHO.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You just linked another question with the same solution.  Of course it's a frequently asked question, so searching on the title leads to a ton of duplicates.

Comment: @Servy yes, but the [current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211283/c-sharp-parallel-foreach-and-async-combination) duplicate with 1 answer is less likely to be helpful to the OP than the [more popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda) duplicate with 7 answers.

Answer (score 4):

`Parallel` and `async` generally don't work well together.

Here you want to allow multiple HTTP requests to happen simultaneously, but throwing multiple threads at the job will not help.

Instead, just use `async`:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<WebsiteDataModel>> RunDownloadParallelAsync()
{
    return await Task.WhenAll(PrepData().Select(DownloadWebsiteAsync));
}
```

Each request will be sent without waiting for the previous response.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to limit the number of simultaneous "workers", use an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) from [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).