# Nesting async/await

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

as follow ,what's the best way for Run Task simultaneously with async/await functions:

```
private async void ProcessItem()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await this.FetchDeviceData(); //Read From Devices
        await Task.Delay(2000);   //300000
        await this.Process(); //Insert Into DataBase
    }
}

private async Task FetchDeviceData()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Read From all Devices;
    }
} 

private async Task Process()
{
    if (!(await RDataBase.ProcessItem(Mem,Date)))
    //Update Record;
}

public static async Task<bool> ProcessItem(int Memb, int Date)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            //Array List = Read Device Info From DataBase
            return True;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear on what you are asking? As I can infer from your code, the `Delay` should run after the `FecthDeviceData` has completed its work and `Process` after the `Delay`.  Isn't that true? If so, I don't get your question. Thanks

Comment: @Christos Tasks Should be run simultaneously

Comment: public static async Task<bool> ProcessItem(int Memb, int Date)
     {
     return await Task.Run(() =>
     {
     try
     {
     
     return True;
     }
     catch
     {
     return false;
     }
     });
     }

Comment: I don't get why you want to fetch data, execute an arbitrary delay, _and_ insert data into a database concurrently, especially if the data you're inserting in the database is related to the data you're fetching. But, whatever. You asked for it, you got it. See marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do all three operation in parallel you should use Task.WhenAll.

```
var task1 = this.FetchDeviceData(); //Read From Devices
var task2 = Task.Delay(2000);   //300000
var task3 = this.Process(); //Insert Into DataBase
await Task.WhenAll(new Task[]{task1,task2,task3 });
```

For More detail see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337671/using-async-await-for-multiple-tasks) post.

Comment: I changed my code based of above , when Task.WhenAll is Finished? and is it true that use this code in While?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to process tasks in some order. Look at [How to: Chain Multiple Tasks with Continuations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: thanks , but as refere to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/enus/dotnet/csharp/async) , i wrote my code using await/async functions