# c# Executing Multiple calls in Parallel

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm looping through an `Array` of values, for each value I want to execute a long running process. Since I have multiple tasks to be performed that have no inter dependency I want to be able to execute them in parallel.

My code is:

```
List<Task<bool>> dependantTasksQuery = new List<Task<bool>>();

foreach (int dependantID in dependantIDList)
{   
    dependantTasksQuery.Add(WaitForDependantObject(dependantID));                                
}

Task<bool>[] dependantTasks = dependantTasksQuery.ToArray();

//Wait for all dependant tasks to complete
bool[] lengths = await Task.WhenAll(dependantTasks);
```

The `WaitForDependantObject` method just looks like:

```
async Task<bool> WaitForDependantObject(int idVal)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);

    bool waitDone = true;            

    return waitDone;
}
```

As you can see I've just added a sleep to highlight my issue.  What is happening when debugging is that on the line:

```
dependantTasksQuery.Add(WaitForDependantObject(dependantID));
```

My code is stopping and waiting the 20 seconds for the method to complete.  I did not want to start the execution until I had completed the loop and built up the Array.  Can somebody point me to what I'm doing wrong?  I'm pretty sure I need an `await` somewhere

Comment: Please post code that compiles - `WaitForDependantObject` have no chance to be compilable as shown. Note that `Sleep` should be used to imitate long CPU intesive task, use `Task.Delay` as replacement for long IO bound work.

Comment: Should compile now, thread.sleep is purely to force a delay. This is just a sample and not my actual code, it's only used to demonstrate my issue.

Comment: You don't have any asynchronous methods. `WaitForDependantObject` blocks synchronously. `async` doesn't make a method asynchronous, it allows you to use the `await` keyword inside its body.

Comment: I've added answer showing proper "sample of async method" (which would work with original code, still would show delays for "synchronous part" and if using WPF/WinForms all results come back to original thread).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx).

Replace this:

```
dependantTasksQuery.Add(WaitForDependantObject(dependantID));
```

with this:

```
dependantTasksQuery.Add(
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => WaitForDependantObject(dependantID)
    )
);
```

This will run your method within a new `Task` and add the task to your `List`.

You will also want to change the method signature of `WaitForDependantObject` to be:

```
bool WaitForDependantObject(int idVal)
```

You can then wait for your tasks to complete with:

```
Task.WaitAll(dependentTasksQuery.ToArray());
```

And get your results with:

```
bool[] lengths = dependentTasksQuery.Select(task => task.Result).ToArray();
```

Comment: Even if the calls are not asynchronous you should still you `await Task.WhenAll` instead of blocking the calling thread.

Comment: @I3arnon So, I guess I've been doing asynchronous wrong in C#. I just read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6123406/2479481). It seems to me that `Task.WaitAll` *could* be appropriate *if* you need the results of your `Task`s in order to continue. Is this correct?

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` returns the results, `Task.WaitAll` doesn't. The issue here is blocking vs asynchronously waiting for completion. blocking is usually bad as it uses up a thread without executing anything and so hinders scalability.

Answer (score 4):

In your case `WaitForDependantObject` isn't asynchronous at all even though it returns a task. If that's your goal do as Luke Willis suggests. To make these calls both asynchronous **and** truly parallel you need to offload them to a Thread Pool thread with `Task.Run`:

```
bool[] lengths = await Task.WhenAll(dependantIDList.Select(() => Task.Run(() => WaitForDependantObject(dependantID))));
```

`async` methods run synchronously until an `await` is reached and them returns a task representing the asynchronous operation. In your case you don't have an `await` so the methods simply execute one after the other. `Task.Run` uses multiple threads to enable parallelism even on these synchronous parts on top of the concurrency of `await`ing all the tasks together with `Task.WhenAll`.

For `WaitForDependantObject` to represent an `async` method more accurately it should look like this:

```
async Task<bool> WaitForDependantObject(int idVal)
{
    await Task.Delay(20000);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, Luke's answer accomplishes what I need so I've accepted it. I've Up-voted this answer as it is good to know for future reference.

Comment: @keitn Then I would suggest updating your title, as your question doesn't regard `async` calls

Answer (score 0):

Use `Task.Delay` to make method asynchronous and looking more real replacement of mocked code:

```
async Task<bool> WaitForDependantObject(int idVal)
{
   // how long synchronous part of method takes (before first await)
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

   // method returns as soon as awiting started    
   await Task.Delay(2000); // how long IO or other async operation takes place

   // simulate data processing, would run on new thread unless 
   // used in WPF/WinForms/ASP.Net and no call to ConfigureAwait(false) made by caller.
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

   bool waitDone = true;            

   return waitDone;
}
```