# What is the difference between WaitAll and WhenAll?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have this code:

```
List<ComponentesClasificaciones> misClasificaciones = new List<ComponentesClasificaciones>();
            Task tskClasificaciones = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    misClasificaciones = VariablesGlobales.Repositorio.buscarComponentesClasificacionesTodosAsync().Result;
                });

Task.WhenAll(tskClasificaciones);

List<ComponentesClasificaciones> misVClasificacionesParaEstructuras = new List<ComponentesClasificaciones>(misClasificaciones);
```

If I use `Task.WhenAll`, `misClasificaciones` does not have any element but when I use awit all I get all the elements that I request to the database.

When to use `WhenAll` and when to use `WaitAll`?

Comment: You can `await` Task.WhenAll without blocking the calling thread.

Comment: Exception handling is different as well, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall

Answer (score 27, accepted):

MSDN does a good job of explaining this. The difference is pretty unambiguous.

#### [Task.WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have completed.

#### [Task.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

So, essentially, `WhenAll` gives you a task that isn't done until all of the tasks you give it are done (and allows program execution to continue immediately), whereas `WaitAll` just blocks and waits for all of the tasks you pass to finish.

Answer (score 18):

`WhenAll` returns a task that you can `ContinueWith` once all the specified tasks are complete. You should be doing

```
Task.WhenAll(tskClasificaciones).ContinueWith(t => {
  // code here
});
```

Basically, use `WaitAll` when you want to synchronously get the results, use `WhenAll` when you want to start a new asynchronous task to start some more processing

Comment: What's the difference between using `ContinueWith` here versus just using `await` on the returned task?

Comment: I think @Vapid asked a good question.