# Access results in Enumerable.Range without having to wait for all tasks to complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, range, ienumerable

I have a console app, where I need to access some url 200 times, **wait for all of the requests to return** and work on the 200 results.

I did it like that, in parallel:

```
var classNameTasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(i => webApi.getSplittedClassName()).ToArray();
string[][] splittedClassNames = await Task.WhenAll(classNameTasks);
if (splittedClassNames[0] == null)
    result = new TextResult("Error accessing the web");
```

`getSplittedClassName` returns a `string[]`, if the internet is off it will return `null`.

Now, as you can see, after the completion of all the tasks, I do an **if** to check the content, if its `null` -> internet issues.

The problem here is that I need to wait for the whole 200 requests to return before I can check the content.

I am looking for a way to right away detect a scenario where there is no internet, and I return null, without having to wait for the 200 requests.

Comment: Do you expect the Internet to fall down *during the task execution?*  Or can you check for internet just prior to starting the tasks?

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27238232

Comment: umm, I guess it could be both options. I am just trying to catch all the errors that can happen

Comment: Do you want to wait on *all* tasks to complete before beginning work on them, or can you work on tasks as they are completed?

Comment: I could maybe do it without waiting for all the tasks, that will require changing my code. how would you go about  it?

Comment: I would probably use continuations.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [Process Tasks By Completion](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2015/06/process-tasks-by-completion.html) (in Russian) and [sources on github](//github.com/SergeyTeplyakov/TplTipsAndTricks)

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need

1. A CancellationTokenSource to signal that the job is done.
2. The WhenAll method from [Tortuga.Anchor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tortuga.Anchor/)

   ```
   static async Task Test()
   {
       TextResult result;

       var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

       var classNameTasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(i => getSplittedClassName(cts)).ToArray();
       await classNameTasks.WhenAll(cts.Token);
       if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
           result = new TextResult("Error accessing the web");

       string[][] splittedClassNames = classNameTasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToArray();

   }

   private static async Task<string[]> getSplittedClassName(CancellationTokenSource cts)
   {
       try
       {
           //real code goes here
           await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token); //the token would be passed to the real web method
           return new string[0];
       }
       catch
       {
           cts.Cancel(); //stop trying
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: this is the right approach, although it would have been more correct (or - aligned with the OP) if instead of try/catch block the token is canceled in case of null value response (rather than exception)

Comment: I fixed the return to be null, but I think there is still a bug. If I'm not mistaken, `await classNameTasks.WhenAll(cts.Token);` will throw an `AggregateException` containing a  `OperationCanceledException`;