# How to cancel and raise an exception on Task.WhenAll if any exception is raised?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I am waiting on multiples task using Task.WhenAll. When one of them generates an exception I would like Task.WhenAll (or any other way of awaiting multiples tasks) to immediately cancel the others tasks and raise an exception.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you check this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238232/how-can-i-cancel-task-whenall

Comment: That's not the way WhenAll works.  You probably need to re-think your approach a bit.

Comment: @EvertonSantos thanks for the link! but my case is different, I need to watch for exception. If an exception is raised inside a task, I need to cancel all the tasks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Cancellation is coopertive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx) the `WhenAll` can't cancel the threads but you can pass all of them a `CancellationToken` and fire the token when you get a exception.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var task1 = Func1Async(cts.Token);
task1.ContinueWith(task => cts.Cancel(), cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
var task2 = Func2Async(cts.Token);
task2.ContinueWith(task => cts.Cancel(), cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
var task3 = Func3Async(cts.Token);
task3.ContinueWith(task => cts.Cancel(), cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

from inside the methods you will need to put `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` inside the functions to check the token and cancel the task

```
public async Task Func1Async(CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach(var item in GetItems1())
    {
         await item.ProcessAsync(token);
         token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

---

NOTE: You could clean up the code a bit by making a extension method

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Task CancelOnFaulted(this Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(task => cts.Cancel(), cts.Token, taskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
        return task;
    }

    public static Task<T> CancelOnFaulted<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(task => cts.Cancel(), cts.Token, taskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
        return task;
    }
}
```

This would make the code look like

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var task1 = Func1Async(cts.Token).CancelOnFaulted(cts);
var task2 = Func2Async(cts.Token).CancelOnFaulted(cts);
var task3 = Func3Async(cts.Token).CancelOnFaulted(cts);

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

Comment: The OP asked about `WhenAll` not `WaitAll`.

Comment: @DavidPine That was a typo in the first sentence, if you look at the code example it uses WhenAll there.

Comment: I assumed as much, didn't want to edit your answer without knowing whether or not that was intentional.

Comment: Useful! You forgot to make the extension methods in your example static.