# Don't wait for other task to finish when a specific task has no result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

Let's say i have 2 task (A and B). I can run them in parallel completely, so i can use:

```
await Task.WhenAll(A,B)
var resA = await A;
var resB = await B;
```

Now i would like to not wait for B if A (based on some condition) returns false. The result of B does not interest me anymore. Can this be done?

---

### [**In addition to this answers below:**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45416292/2046432)

So just to be sure, a Task starts immediately when creating one. So the following code should work.

```
var A = Usermanager.FindAsync(email.ToString(), password.ToString());
var B = db.Table.AnyAsync(r=> r.email == email.Tostring()); //simplified action
var user = await A;
if (user != null)
{
    var resB = await B;
}
else
{
    // A was false, so don't await B
}
```

And if B generates a long running sql-statement. Would it be better to still use the cancellation token resulting in following code to free up the SQL Servers resources?

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var A = Usermanager.FindAsync(email.ToString(), password.ToString());
var B = db.Table.AnyAsync(r=> r.email == email.Tostring(), cts.Token); //simplified long running sql action
var user = await A;
if (user != null)
{
    var resB = await B;
}
else
{
    // A was false, cancel query from B
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now i would like to not wait for B if A (based on some condition) returns false. The result of B does not interest me anymore. Can this be done?

Sure, just don't `await` it:

```
if (await A)
{
  var resB = await B;
}
else
{
  // A was false, so don't await B
}
```

Comment: this way both actions are executed synchronous (in perspective to each other) I would like to start A and B at the same time (async) but Ignore B

Comment: @Dexter Then start `B` before awaiting `A`, just don't `await` B.

Comment: @Dexter: In this code, `A` and `B` are both tasks, and they are both already in progress. They are not executed synchronously nor serially.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I edited the question with a followup base on your answer. It wouldn't fit in a comment.

Comment: @Dexter: Yes, [TAP tasks are returned "hot"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#task-status) - that is, already in progress. And yes, if `B` is long running and consuming resources and cancelable, then it would be a good idea to cancel it as per your code.

Comment: then the real question for task B is: Are EF6 queries cancalable once send to the SQL-Server. I couldn't find a satisfying answer telling why ore why not.

Comment: @Dexter: Ah, yes. I don't know whether those are truly cancelable. But if they're not, there isn't anything you can do about it anyway (short of killing the db connection).

Answer (score -2):

a removed answer was linking to [How to cancel and raise an exception on Task.WhenAll if any exception is raised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899842/how-to-cancel-and-raise-an-exception-on-task-whenall-if-any-exception-is-raised/41900329#41900329). But guessing on the mins following code is not the correct way to go:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var A = Usermanager.FindAsync(email.ToString(), password.ToString());
var B = db.Table.AnyAsync(r=> r.email == email.Tostring(), cts.Token) //simplified action
var C = A.ContinueWith(t => { if (t.Result == null) { cts.Cancel(); } }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
await Task.WhenAll(C,B);
```

Of course you can change the ContinuationOption, but to use the result of a task, i believe it should be OnlyRanToCompletion. Above should cancel B and therefor finish the Task.WhenAll command when A has a result of null (no result).