# Waiting on tasks where number of tasks could vary

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task

I need to wait for one or more tasks to complete. The number of tasks that I need to wait on depends upon a few conditions. So my code is something like below.

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[2];

if (condition1 == true)
{
    tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod1());
}

if (condition2 == true)
{
    tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod2());
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Let's say `condition2` is false, so there is only one item in the tasks array. Will the `WaitAll` only wait for `tasks[0]` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx) throw ArgumentException if any element of the tasks array is null.

To avoid the exception, you can add your tasks to a `List<Task>` instead:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

if (condition1)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod1()));
}

if (condition2)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod2()));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: One should not really be using `WaitAll` (instead of `WhenAll` with proper `async`/`await`), but indeed this is the right answer as OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use WhenAll which supports IEnumerable as parameter. This allows you to use a different container than an array and will avoid the exception in the first place.

```
List<Task> tasks= new List<Task>();

if (condition1)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod1()));
}

if (condition2)
{ 
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod2()));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

See also [WaitAll vs WhenAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall)