# WhenAll() not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library, begininvoke

I need to make UI thread wait until a task array completes execution.The problem with below code is that - the tasks inturn invoke UI thread to write into textbox. How to fix this?

```
public partial class FormConsole : Form
{
    public FormConsole()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void txtSayHello_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 objclss = new Class1();
        objclss.formConsole = this;

        Task[] taa = new Task[4];
        taa[0] = new Task(() => objclss.DoSomeThigs("Hello world"));
        taa[1] = new Task(() => objclss.DoSomeThigs("Hello world1"));
        taa[2] = new Task(() => objclss.DoSomeThigs("Hello world2"));
        taa[3] = new Task(() => objclss.DoSomeThigs("Hello world3"));

        foreach(Task task in taa)
        {
            task.Start();
        }
        Task.WhenAll(taa);
        this.txtConsole.AppendText("All threads complete");
    }

    delegate void doStuffDelegate(string value);

    public void doStuff(string value)
    {        
        if (System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.InvokeRequired && IsHandleCreated)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new doStuffDelegate(doStuff), value);        
        }
        else
            txtConsole.AppendText(value);        
    }

}

public class Class1
{
    public FormConsole formConsole;
    public void DoSomeThigs(string sampleText)
    {
        formConsole.doStuff(sampleText);
    }
}
```

o/p now : `Console Redirection TestAll threads completeHello worldHello world1Hello world2Hello world3`

o/p I want : `Console Redirection TestHello worldHello world1Hello world2Hello world3All threads complete`

What's the solution?

Comment: I suspect you want to use `WaitAll` instead of `WhenAll`. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall

Comment: That works the same way!! tried that

Comment: actually, it doesn't.

Comment: the answer by @Jakub Lortz works!! i had to use asyn and await

Comment: It works, really? Probably because `WhenAll` does **not** work the same way as `WaitAll`, as @Filip already mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` returns a `Task` representing the completion of all these tasks in the enumerable. You need to await that task as the method doesn't block the thread.

Turn `txtSayHello_Click` into an `async void` (which should only be used for event handlers) method and await the task returned from `Task.WhenAll`:

```
async void txtSayHello_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    await Task.WhenAll(taa);
    // ...
}
```

Moreover, you should almost always avoid using the `Task` constructor. You should use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `TaskScheduler.FromSynchronizationContext` if you need the task to run on the UI thread (that depends on what you actually do with `FormConsole`) or `Task.Run` if you don't. Meaning:

```
taa[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objclss.DoSomeThigs("Hello world"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Or:

```
taa[0] = Task.Run(() => objclss.DoSomeThigs("Hello world"));
```

Answer (score 5):

`Task.WhenAll` returns a task that completes when all tasks passed to it complete. You have to `await` this task, otherwise the method will continue executing.

```
async void txtSayHello_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    await Task.WhenAll(taa);
    ...
}
```

There is a blocking version of this method - `Task.WaitAll`. It will block the current thread until all tasks are done, but it's not a good idea to block the UI thread.

Also, the preferred way to start a task on a thread pool thread is to use `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 3):

You're most likely confusing `WhenAll()` with `WaitAll()`.
As already suggested you can use `async` with `await` or you can simply use :

A) `Task.WhenAll(taa).Wait();`

B) `Task.WaitAll(taa);`

But in your case this will block UI thread. So it's better to put rest of the code to Continuation Task and invoke UI operations with `Control.Invoke()` :

```
Task.WhenAll(taa).ContinueWith(t =>
{
   this.Invoke(() => this.txtConsole.AppendText("All threads complete"));
});
```

Comment: o/p after trying this (Not working in my case): Console Redirection TestAll threads completeHello worldHello world1Hello world2Hello world3.

Comment: using only continueWith gives error `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtConsole' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.` but using async-await works.

Comment: @flute with async code that follows await statement is executed with first available thread from the `TreadPool` with priority set to thread that was used when async method was started. If UI thread enters method (which is most likely the case here) then async-await will attempt to use it to execute code after `await` but if UI thread is busy (even for a second) then you'll see this excepiton with async-await too. If you'll envelope your UI call with `this.Invoke(() => { MyCode... });` you'll have 100% that it'll be invoked on same thread. Updated my answer.