# Get the content of website using HttpClient but without async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, asynchronous, html-agility-pack

I am trying to fetch the website content using `httpclinet as you can see here

```
public async Task<List<NewsContent>> parsing(string newsArchive)
{
    List<NewsContent> lstResult=new List<NewsContent>();
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(newsArchive);
    String source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
    source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
    HtmlDocument resultat = new HtmlDocument();
    resultat.LoadHtml(source);

    List<HtmlNode> toftitle = resultat.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where
    (x => (x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("news_list"))).ToList();
    var li = toftitle[0].Descendants().Where
    (x => (x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value=="news_item")).ToList();

    foreach (var item in li)
    {
        NewsContent newsContent = new NewsContent();
        newsContent.Url = item.Descendants("a").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("href", null);
        newsContent.Img = item.Descendants("img").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("src", null);
        newsContent.Title = item.Descendants("h2").ToList()[0].InnerText;

        //finding main news content
        var response1 = await http.GetByteArrayAsync("http://www.nsfund.ir/news" + newsContent.Url);
        String source1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response1, 0, response1.Length - 1);
        source1 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source1);
        HtmlDocument resultat1 = new HtmlDocument();
        resultat1.LoadHtml(source1);
        newsContent.Content = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='news_content_container']").InnerText;


    }
    return  lstResult;
}
```

As you can see i used `async` method to get the data .here :

```
var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(newsArchive);
```

But the problem is when i call my `async` function :

```
News newagent = new News();
Task<List<NewsContent>> lst = newagent.parsing("http://www.nsfund.ir");
Task.WaitAll(lst);
List<NewsContent> enresult = lst.Result;
```

I don't get any result.so i decided to convert this `async` function to a normal function ,what kind of code should be replaced with this :

```
var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(newsArchive);
```

Comment: Try `var response = http.GetByteArrayAsync(newsArchive).Result;`. It probably won't help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess i found the problem with your code.
You're not adding the `NewsContent` object to your `List`.

in the `foreach` loop please add it to the `List`

`lstResult.Add(newsContent)`

Hope it solves the issue with your `async` strategy

Comment: Thank you ,you are right ,i am running my code to check the result

Comment: But one question should i use Task.WaitAll(lst); or Task.WhenAll(lst)?

Comment: use Task.WaitAll(lst); . Task.WhenAll(lst) returns a Task that will complete when all the tasks passed have completed. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall

Comment: I run the code i put a breakpoint in foreach loop .but the loop never executed why?

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is when i call my async function :

```
Task.WaitAll(lst);
List<NewsContent> enresult = lst.Result;
```

Yes, that's a problem, all right. Two problems, actually: `Task.WaitAll` and `Result`. They should both be replaced with a single `await`:

```
List<NewsContent> enresult = await lst;
```

The core problem is a [deadlock scenario](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain in full on my blog. In summary, `await` will capture the current context and use that to resume the `async` method. But ASP.NET only allows one thread within its request context at a time. So when `parsing` is first called, it executes until it hits its `await` and then returns. The calling method then blocks; this is where the problem is, because by blocking, the calling method is keeping a thread in that ASP.NET request context.

Later, when the `await` inside `parsing` is done, it attempts to resume the `parsing` method in that ASP.NET request context but it cannot, because there's a thread stuck in that context and ASP.NET only allows one thread at a time. The calling method is waiting for `parsing` to complete, and `parsing` is waiting for the context to be free. Classic deadlock.

Comment: Stephen's blog posts regarding `async`/`await` are *invaluable*.  If anyone is even the slightest bit confused by how they work, I highly recommend checking them out.