# 'TaskEx' doesn't work!(BCL)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, base-class-library

i am new guy here.

I have a complicate problem.

I am using .net 4.0 MVC 4, add References about Microsoft BLC for using async, await.

and wrote

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx.WhenAll(tl);
```

for wait Threads work ends of course.
But error pops out here.

```
Error   13  The type or namespace name 'TaskEx' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading.Tasks' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I tested many times another Project on another Solution, but it's work. not like this.

Any ideas for little help?

whole Method here.

```
public async void SendEmailEwsAsync(string subject, string mailBody, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> tl = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
            foreach (var kvp in Receivers)
            {
                EmailMessage mail = CreateMailEws(subject, mailBody);

                mail.ToRecipients.Add(kvp.Value);
                if (!this.TestFlag)
                {
                    mail.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(string.Format(fileName, EmailNamePair[kvp.Value]), kvp.Key);
                }

                tl.Add(TaskSendAsync(mail));
                this.CurrentCursor++;
            }
            await System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx.WhenAll(tl); //error here
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.IsEnd = true;
        }
    }

    private System.Threading.Tasks.Task TaskSendAsync(EmailMessage mail)
    {
        Action action = delegate()
        {
            mail.Save(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts, new Mailbox("noreply@whatever.com"))); 
            mail.SendAndSaveCopy(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, new Mailbox("noreply@whatever.com"))); 
        };
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(action);
        task.Start();
        return task;
    }
```

whole References here

[Project References List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWmAV.png)

Thank you for see this.

Comment: If you mean ASP.NET MVC, you can't use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` on ASP.NET. Even if you get it to compile (which is possible), it will not behave properly at runtime.

Comment: @StephenCleary for real? Actually, I did add References about MVC in this project, but it's A kind of common library in my another MVC project. so I remove MVC reference, but still doesn't work.

Comment: To be clear, `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` cannot be used on ASP.NET at all. To use `async` on ASP.NET, you have to upgrade to at least .NET 4.5.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes. but I using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` from nuget for .NET 4.5 Below.

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to reference TaskEx, and you can do WaitAll instead of WhenAll

```
// Wait for all tasks in list to complete
Task.WaitAll(tl);
```

Comment: Thx for your comment! one question, is that exactly same work? between TaskEx.WhenAll() and Task.WaitAll() ?

Comment: The WhenAll() method will actually create a new, awaitable task that you can await, while the WaitAll() doesen't. Fine grained difference there, and all depends of course of what you want to. There is a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall

Comment: I already have Syncronous method. so I want make Asyncronous one. Seem like WaitAll() is Block type right? but still I thanks for your attention.

Comment: Try without TaskEx. I've never used it, only Task.WhenAll(tl)

Comment: Task.WhenAll() is not supported below less than .net 4.5