# Call same method many times at once

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have this simple method:

```
static void Extract()
{
    Interlocked.Add(ref Program.n, 1);
    Console.WriteLine("Currently on: " + n + " Page");
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading String...Extract...");
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string html = client.DownloadString("www.something.com&page=" + n);
    Console.WriteLine("Proccesing data from string... (Extract)");   
}
```

I want to call method `Extract()` few times at once and I tried this:

```
while(n<3411)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(Extract)));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);       
}
```

But I get error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' RecipeCommunity_Users   C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\Community_Users\Program.cs   24  Active

How I can call method `Extract()` many times at once ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) method's signature is:

```
public static void WaitAll(params Task[] tasks);
```

It receives a `Task[]` and not a list. Change to:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

---

Depending on the usage it might be better to use `WhenAll` as L.B stated in his answer. Then use this way:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

See this question: [WaitAll vs WhenAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall). In short `WaitAll` blocks the thread while `WhenAll` itself doesn't.

*As Eser menthioned in the comments the use of `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result` will block the thread but that is due to blocking the task that `WhenAll` returns*

Comment: `in short WaitAll blocks the thread while WhenAll doesn't` No. `WhenAll` can block the current thread too.. `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result` It is all related to how you use the tools

Comment: @Eser - yes but not because of `WhenAll` but because of the why you decide to use the `Task` it returns... Forgive me if it wasn't you but I think this is an unprofessional downvote...

Answer (score 10):

All you need is

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Different then [WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx), It doesn't accepts `IEnumerable<Task>`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx

Your another option could be

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```