# C# Task.Delay blocks second task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I want to run two tasks.

`StartAccessTokenTimer()` runs every 60 seconds and refreshes accesstoken variable.
`StartItemsTimer()` will start after `StartAccessTokenTimer()` and work every 3 seconds if access token get.

```
    private accessToken = "";

    private async Task StartAccessTokenTimer()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

        while (true)
        {
            accesstoken = await GetAccessToken();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), source.Token);
        }
    }

    private async Task StartItemsTimer()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

        while (true)
        {
            var items = await GetItems(accessToken, "1");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), source.Token);
        }
    }

    public async Task StartOperations(){
        await StartAccessTokenTimer();
        await StartItemsTimer();
    }
```

But it does not filre `GetItems()` methot. Because `StartAccessTokenTimer()` never start.. It fires  `GetAccessToken()` continiously.

Comment: You are awaiting StartAccessTokenTimer(), until it returns, its not going to call StartItemsTimer(), also I see no break for your while loop so its going to continue awaiting StartAccessTokenTimer() to return

Comment: Updates? Refreshes you mean? Isn't it a bit wasteful to have a loop just sit updating the token?

Comment: Yes refreshes toke, I will update the post.

Comment: Couldn't you just refresh the token when you try to make a request but get a 401 back (instead of this application-long loop)?

Comment: do you want to do `await Task.WhenAll(StartAccessTokenTimer(),StartItemsTimer())` with some additional synchronization of variables?

Comment: There's no block in this code. Your `StartAccessTokenTimer` never exits, it keeps refreshing the token. `await` doesn't make anything run in asynchronously, it *awaits* for an asynchronous operation to finish, then continues execution. Something I've already posted as a comment in your *previous* question.

Comment: What do you want to actually do? If the token is refreshed, are you going to keep refreshing? In this case why not get the token before every call to `GetItems`? All previous tokens will be wasted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos access token expires in 60 seconds. So I will refresh it every 60 sec. But I am getting items every 3 seconds. I wil do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger them to fire at the same time you can do the following:

```
public async Task StartOperations()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] 
    {
        StartAccessTokenTimer(),
        StartItemsTimer()
    });
}
```

Comment: WaitAll vs WhenAll
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Or simply `new[]`