# How can I get the result from WhenAll(Array of tasks)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code.

```cs
var tasks = new[]
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething1()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething2()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething3())
    };

var things = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

How can I get the results from all three tasks separately and print them?

Comment: Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall

Comment: If the `Get..` methods are all asynchronous (returning `Task`s of their own), you don't need `.StartNew`. If they're all synchronous and their number could be variable (based on other collections), consider using `Enumerable.AsParallel` (PLINQ) or `Parallel.For[Each]` to parallelize the work, rather than wrapping them as tasks.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That's along the right path, but your call to `WhenAll` is superfluous if using `Result` on each task straight after.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the results seperately you have multiple ways I would do something like this:

```
var task1  = GetSomething1();
var task2  = GetSomething2();
var task3  = GetSomething3();

// your method will continue when everything's completed, but you won't tie up a thread to just hang around until that time.
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

var result1 = await task1;
var result2 = await task2;
var result3 = await task3;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and won't compile if the `GetSomethingX` methods don't return `Task`s (which I doubt they do). If they do, then the call to `WhenAll` is superfluous, especially as it's not clear if `GetSomethingX` is returning `Task<T>` or `Task<Task<T>>`.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to make each `Task` responsible for storing its own result, and then all you have to do is `await` the collection of Tasks. Note that you'll have to use `await` to make the `WhenAll()` execute the tasks that you pass into it.

```
var results = new int[3];

var tasks = new[] {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results[0] = GetSomething1()), 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results[1] = GetSomething2()), 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results[2] = GetSomething3())
};

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Console.WriteLine(results[0]);
Console.WriteLine(results[1]);
Console.WriteLine(results[2]);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HS32QA

Note that you may need to be careful with using e.g. a `List<T>` instead of an array, and then calling `list.Add(result)`, as there is no guarantee of the order in which the tasks are executed or when they will be finished.

Comment: The real issue with `List.Add` is not any of order but the simple fact that it's not thread-safe. You'd need explicit locks or something like `ConcurrentBag` to work around that. However, by that point an approach like this is probably unnecessarily complicated and only worth considering if the number of results per task is variable. Otherwise, there's no real reason not to use the fact that tasks have built-in support for results (as used in the other answers).

Answer (score -1):

You should use `async..await` pattern with `When`, e.g.

```
  private async Task MyExecution() {
    var tasks = new[] {
      //TODO: Task.Run is a better option than Task.Factory.StartNew
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething1()),
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething2()),
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething3())
    };

    // Await until all tasks are completed 
    var things = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    // Let's print the things
    for (int i = 0; i < things.Length; ++i) 
      Console.WriteLine($"Task #{i + 1} returned {things[i]}");

    ... 
  }
```

Comment: [`Task.WhenAll<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___) returns a `Task<TResult[]>`. Awaiting this task returns an array with the results. No need for the `.Select.ToArray` stuff.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a similar solution and found it after a while in the edit-note of [this blogpost](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2021/02/15/c-get-results-from-task-whenall/):

You need to define the List of tasks as tasks with a return type `List<Task<T>>()`, in my case int. Then you can use either WaitAll or WhenAll and check the task List afterwards like this:

`var anyErrorTwo = tasks.Any(task => task.Result.Equals(-2));`

Without testing your exact code snippet, I assume that `new[]` creates an array of void Tasks like `List<Task>()` which will work for waiting, but not for retrieving a result which has then been ignored.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered actually using async functions? Then you have an array of tasks with the results, and avoid the highly unpredictable behaviours of `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

```cs
private async Task MyExecution() 
{
    var tasks = new[] {
        GetSomething1(),
        GetSomething2(),
        GetSomething3()
    };

    // Await until all tasks are completed 
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    foreach(var t in tasks){
        //t.Result is available
    }
}

public static async Task<int> GetSomething1() { return 1; }
public static async Task<int> GetSomething2() { return 2; }
public static async Task<int> GetSomething3() { return 3; }
```

Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ffs9L

Comment: What would those "highly unpredictable behaviors" be? Wrapping synchronous code has its issues, but those are not specific to `StartNew`. The `async` methods you offer by way of example are not themselves asynchronous, and could mislead people into thinking that slapping on `async Task` is enough to turn a synchronous function into an asynchronous one. In reality, in this particular code snippet the results are all available whether or not you ever call `await Task.WhenAll`, as the code is executed synchronously when the array is created.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Not sure why you think the original code wraps synchronous code. Some of the problems with StartNew can be found [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), [here](https://sergeyteplyakov.github.io/Blog/async/2019/05/21/The-Dangers-of-Task.Factory.StartNew.html), and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/). 

The async methods I offer are simply an example and you're correct: they run synchronously. In fact, the compiler will warn of precisely that.

Comment: You're right, that's an assumption based on the fact that if the `Get...` methods already returned `Task`s, there'd be no reason to plug them into `.StartNew()` in the first place -- but the OP might not have been aware of that. Your answer would be improved by actually linking to the problems of `.StartNew()` in there -- I wouldn't call those pitfalls "unpredictable"!