# Task.WaitAll causes thread starvation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I have background job and every 15s I am making arrount 10000 redis calls 1000 at a time. I put all the tasks in an Array then I do Task.WaitAll(array).
The machine have 32 cors. The redis cluster is 3 masters and 3 slaves in sperate vms. If I let it run for 30 minutes this will cause a thread starvation. So changing the "WaitAll" with "WhenAll" will it solve the problem and why?

Comment: can you show some code example?

Comment: It’s my understanding that WaitAll is a blocking method still while WhenAll is Async.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall