# Task WaitAll return List object in c#

Tags: c#, task

I have created this code to understand about "Task.WaitAll ()" in c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace taskApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Task> p = new List<Task>();

            Task task1 = MultipleTasks();
            Task task2 = Hello(40);
            Task task3 = Bye(10);
            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);

            var a = 1;
            a = a + 1;
        }

        private static async Task Hello(int delay)
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ End Process: {nameof(Hello)}, delay: {delay} +++ ");
        }

        private static async Task Bye(int delay)
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ End Process: {nameof(Bye)}, delay: {delay} +++ ");
        }
        private static async Task<List<MyClass>> MultipleTasks()
        {
            List<Task<MyClass>> psTask = new List<Task<MyClass>>();
            List<MyClass> ps = new List<MyClass>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                psTask.Add(getTest(i));

            Task.WaitAll(psTask.ToArray());

            ps = psTask.Select(c => c.Result).ToList();

            return ps;
        }

        private static async Task<MyClass> getTest(int i)
        {
            MyClass p = new MyClass();
            int delay = 0;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    delay = 4000;
                    p.delayUsed = delay;
                    p.message = "cero";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    delay = 1000;
                    p.delayUsed = delay;
                    p.message = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    delay = 7000;
                    p.delayUsed = delay;
                    p.message = "dos";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    delay = 2000;
                    p.delayUsed = delay;
                    p.message = "tres";
                    break;
                default:
                    p.message = "default";
                    break;
            }

            await Task.Delay(p.delayUsed);
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ End Process: {nameof(getTest)} {i}, delay: {delay} +++ ");
            return p;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int delayUsed { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the order that the console application runs

```
+++ End Process: getTest 1, delay: 1000 +++
+++ End Process: getTest 0, delay: 4000 +++
+++ End Process: getTest 2, delay: 7000 +++
+++ End Process: Bye, delay: 10 +++
+++ End Process: Hello, delay: 40 +++
```

The correct order that my application should run is as follows:

```
+++ End Process: Bye, delay: 10 +++
+++ End Process: Hello, delay: 40 +++
+++ End Process: getTest 1, delay: 1000 +++
+++ End Process: getTest 0, delay: 4000 +++
+++ End Process: getTest 2, delay: 7000 +++
```

Following the logic of the delay time of each method, the correct execution order is deduced

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo5UT.png)

This is the help that "visual studio 2019" gives me.

And effectively the "MultipleTasks ()" method is executed synchronously.

Can someone tell me how I can make the console application behave correctly?.

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` blocks the thread. You should use `await Task.WhenAll` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WaitAll vs WhenAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're awaiting during the creation of the tasks and not just their execution.

First, change your `MultipleTasks()` method to read like this (returning `List<Task>`):

```
    private static List<Task> MultipleTasks()
    {
        List<Task> psTask = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            psTask.Add(getTest(i));

        return psTask;
    }
```

Then change the `getTest()` method to return `Task`, like this:

```
    private static async Task getTest(int i)
    {
        // snip

        await Task.Delay(p.delayUsed);
        Console.WriteLine($"+++ End Process: {nameof(getTest)} {i}, delay: {delay} +++ ");
    }
```

Finally, create and execute your tasks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = MultipleTasks();

        tasks.Add(Hello(40));
        tasks.Add(Bye(10));
        
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The output should then be what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much dear, I only have one question left that I left in a new comment

Answer (score 0):

This is what i wanted to achieve, thank you very much for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace taskApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ");
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ Asynchronous code +++ ");
            Console.WriteLine($"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ");
            List<Task<MyClass>> tasks = MultipleTasks();
            Task<MyClass> task2 = Hello(400);
            Task<MyClass> task3 = Bye(10);

            tasks.Add(task3);
            tasks.Add(task2);

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            //from here it runs synchronously

            MyClass a = task2.Result;
            MyClass b = task3.Result;

            List<MyClass> c = tasks.Select(c => c.Result).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine($"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ");
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ Synchronous code ++++ ");
            Console.WriteLine($"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ");
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ Run {nameof(task2)}: message {a.message}, delay {a.delayUsed}+++ ");
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ Run {nameof(task3)}: message {b.message}, delay {b.delayUsed}+++ ");
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var item in c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"+++ Run {nameof(tasks)}: message: {item.message}, delay {item.delayUsed} +++ ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ");
        }

        private static async Task<MyClass> Hello(int delay)
        {
            MyClass p = new MyClass();
            p.delayUsed = delay;
            p.message = $"Procedure {nameof(Hello)}";

            await Task.Delay(delay);
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ End Process: {nameof(Hello)}, delay: {delay} +++ ");
            return p;
        }

        private static async Task<MyClass> Bye(int delay)
        {
            MyClass p = new MyClass();
            p.delayUsed = delay;
            p.message = $"Procedure {nameof(Bye)}";
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ End Process: {nameof(Bye)}, delay: {delay} +++ ");
            return p;
        }
        private static List<Task<MyClass>> MultipleTasks()
        {
            List<Task<MyClass>> psTask = new List<Task<MyClass>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                psTask.Add(getTest(i));

            return psTask;
        }

        private static async Task<MyClass> getTest(int i)
        {
            MyClass p = new MyClass();
            int delay = 0;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    delay = 4000;
                    p.delayUsed = delay;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    delay = 1000;
                    p.delayUsed = delay;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    delay = 7000;
                    p.delayUsed = delay;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    delay = 2000;
                    p.delayUsed = delay;
                    break;
                default:
                    delay = 0;
                    break;
            }

            p.message = $"Procedure {nameof(getTest)}({i})";
            await Task.Delay(p.delayUsed);
            Console.WriteLine($"+++ End Process: {nameof(getTest)}({i}), delay: {delay} +++ ");
            return p;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int delayUsed { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Result

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++ Asynchronous code +++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++ End Process: Bye, delay: 10 +++
+++ End Process: Hello, delay: 400 +++
+++ End Process: getTest(1), delay: 1000 +++
+++ End Process: getTest(0), delay: 4000 +++
+++ End Process: getTest(2), delay: 7000 +++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++ Synchronous code ++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++ Run task2: message Procedure Hello, delay 400+++
+++ Run task3: message Procedure Bye, delay 10+++

+++ Run tasks: message: Procedure getTest(0), delay 4000 +++
+++ Run tasks: message: Procedure getTest(1), delay 1000 +++
+++ Run tasks: message: Procedure getTest(2), delay 7000 +++
+++ Run tasks: message: Procedure Bye, delay 10 +++
+++ Run tasks: message: Procedure Hello, delay 400 +++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```