# Is Task.WhenAll(taskList).Wait() the same as Task.WaitAll(taskList)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Are those lines behaving exactly the same (Including Exceptionhandling via AggregateException)?

```
Task.WhenAll(taskList).Wait()
Task.WaitAll(taskList)
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WaitAll vs WhenAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall)

Comment: No. Both block but the first is worse because it didn't have to. It' starts awaiting asynchronously only to get blocked by `Wait()`. Don't block at all instead, use `await Task.WhenAll()`

Comment: If anything, `Task.WhenAll(taskList).Wait()` may result in deeper nesting of the original exceptions, and an `AggregateException(AggregateException(Exception[]))` instead of an `AggregateException(Exception[]))`. Use `await Task.WhenAll()` instead to get the first actual `Exception`

Comment: What is the type of the `taskList`? Is it `List<Task>` or `List<Task<TResult>>`?

Comment: @MarkC. : No, not really, this post brought me to this question.
@PanagiotisKanavos : Yep, I know that, but in my special case, I have to use Wait() and cannot use await. 
@TheodorZoulias : In my particular case a `List<Task<TResult>>`, but do you think that matters for my question?

Thanks @all for your answers. I couldn't identify any difference between these lines, but i will investigate the nesting of the exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find out by experimentation:

```
var task1 = Task.FromResult(13);
var task2 = Task.FromCanceled<int>(new CancellationToken(true));
var task3 = Task.FromCanceled<int>(new CancellationToken(true));
var task4 = Task.FromException<int>(new ApplicationException());
var task5 = Task.FromException<int>(new OverflowException());
Test("Successful+Canceled+Canceled", new[] { task1, task2, task3 });
Test("Successful+Failed+Failed", new[] { task1, task4, task5 });
Test("Successful+Canceled+Failed+Failed", new[] { task1, task2, task4, task5 });
Test("Successful+Canceled+Canceled+Failed", new[] { task1, task2, task3, task4 });

static void Test(string title, Task<int>[] tasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(title);
    try { Task.WaitAll(tasks); }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"WaitAll():      {ToString(ex)}");
    }
    try { Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait(); }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"WhenAll.Wait(): {ToString(ex)}");
    }
}

static string ToString(AggregateException aex) {
    return $"({aex.InnerExceptions.Count}) " +
        String.Join(", ", aex.InnerExceptions.Select(ex => ex.GetType().Name));
}
```

Output:

```
Successful+Canceled+Canceled
WaitAll():      (2) TaskCanceledException, TaskCanceledException
WhenAll.Wait(): (1) TaskCanceledException

Successful+Failed+Failed
WaitAll():      (2) ApplicationException, OverflowException
WhenAll.Wait(): (2) ApplicationException, OverflowException

Successful+Canceled+Failed+Failed
WaitAll():      (3) TaskCanceledException, ApplicationException, OverflowException
WhenAll.Wait(): (2) ApplicationException, OverflowException

Successful+Canceled+Canceled+Failed
WaitAll():      (3) TaskCanceledException, TaskCanceledException, ApplicationException
WhenAll.Wait(): (1) ApplicationException
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ho5A7K).

What we see is that the [`Task.WaitAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall) method propagates the exceptions of the tasks as they are, while the [`Task.WhenAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall).[`Wait()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) approach propagates only a single `TaskCanceledException`, and only when no other type of exception has occurred.

It should also be mentioned that with the `Task.WaitAll` you get more options out of the box, like `millisecondsTimeout`, or `cancellationToken`, or both.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could not be better explained!